# JsonObject JsonArray : get value and make to json

Tags: java, json

This format is what I want :

```
{"data": [{"name": "Sky","account": "k@gmail.com","edit": "1","delete": "1"}]}
```

Now My `jsonArray` is  :

```
 {"name":"Sky","delete":1,"edit":1,"account":"k@gmail.com"}
```

What is the next step ??
Please help me or if there is better solution
please tell me Thank you

```
public String getList() throws JSONException {

        User dataUser  =memberO.getMember(1);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("name", dataUser.getUserName());
        jsonObject.put("account", dataUser.getAccount());
        jsonObject.put("edit", dataUser.getUserId());
        jsonObject.put("delete", dataUser.getUserId());

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        System.out.println(jsonArray);

        String str = "{\"data\": [{\"name\": \""+dataUser.getUserName()+"\",\"account\": \""+dataUser.getAccount()+"\",\"edit\": \""+dataUser.getUserId()+"\",\"delete\": \""+dataUser.getUserId()+"\"}]}";

        return str;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this..this will help you

```
public String getList() throws JSONException {

    User dataUser  =memberO.getMember(1);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("name", dataUser.getUserName());
    jsonObject.put("account", dataUser.getAccount());
    jsonObject.put("edit", dataUser.getUserId());
    jsonObject.put("delete", dataUser.getUserId());

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.add(jsonObject);


    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();
    responseJson.put("data", jsonArray);//Here you can see the data in json format

    return responseJson.toString();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert the `JSONObject`in to a `String`.

```
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    jObject.put("data", jsonArray);

    String jsonText = jObject.toJSONString();
    System.out.println(jsonText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getList() throws JSONException {

    User dataUser  =memberO.getMember(1);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("name", dataUser.getUserName());
    jsonObject.put("account", dataUser.getAccount());
    jsonObject.put("edit", dataUser.getUserId());
    jsonObject.put("delete", dataUser.getUserId());

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    jsonArray.put(0, jsonObject);
    JSONObject topObject = new JSONObject();
    topObject.put("data", jsonArray);
    System.out.println(topObject.toJSONString);
    System.out.println(jsonArray);

    String str = "{\"data\": [{\"name\": \""+dataUser.getUserName()+"\",\"account\": \""+dataUser.getAccount()+"\",\"edit\": \""+dataUser.getUserId()+"\",\"delete\": \""+dataUser.getUserId()+"\"}]}";

    return str;


}
```

Comment: Should I need to import something?? I have error on jsonArray.put

Comment: -````The method put(int, JSONObject) is undefined for the type 
  JSONArray ```` & ````toJSONString cannot be resolved or is not a 
 field````

Comment: Are you using Java EE javax.json package? In this case, try [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#set%28int,%20E%29) instead put

Comment: thank you! I use ````import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;```` . I include the wrong jar on ````JSONArray```` And solve my problem.  And the ````topObject.toJSONString```` should be ````topObject.toString()````